# CORS error on API project. Configuring HTTP headers doesn't work

Tags: http, cors, http-headers

I'm working on an API project. When I try to fetch, I receive the following error on browser console and the app doesn't work.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://rapidapi... (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

[image: cors-error]

I've activated my Internet Information Services (ISS) Manager and added "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to HTTP headers, but nothing changed. I entered "localhost:3000" as the value since it is the origin, but I also tried to enter the API URL. Nothing worked so far. Do you see what am I missing?

[image: http-headers]

Comment: You're handling it on the wrong end of things. The CORS headers need to be in place on the `rapidapi-example-currency-conversion.vercel.app` URL you're accessing. If they're not present, and it's not your API, it's probably intended for server-to-server calls only.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for the tip! The problem was in my _index.js_ file. I was trying to access a completely different server. Solved!